# Why assigning value to str won't throw SyntaxError like it does for True/False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword, built-in

In Python there is the built-in function `str` to convert to a string.
But when I assign a value to `str` I can't use the function any more.
I expect Python not to allow to overload Python reserved words. No?
(Like I can't do `True = False`)

```
>>> i = 12
>>> str(i)
'12'
>>> str = "test"
>>> print(str)
test
>>> str(i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> True = False
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to keyword
>>>
```

I know that it is good practice not to use reserved words.
Still, I'd like to know if I miss something.

I expected Python to throw `SyntaxError`.
In place after that can't use the `str` function.

Comment: I'm afraid your expectations are based on the wrong premisse that `str` (just like other builtin types and functions) is a reserved word. It isn't, so you shouldn't expect a SyntaxError here.

Answer (score 3):

`str` isn't a reserved word, it's a normal function that happens to be built in. `True` and `False` are keywords (since Python 3).

A full list of Python 3 keywords is in [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords):

```
False      await      else       import     pass
None       break      except     in         raise
True       class      finally    is         return
and        continue   for        lambda     try
as         def        from       nonlocal   while
assert     del        global     not        with
async      elif       if         or         yield
```

Answer (score 1):

you can always access the builtins via their package

```
import builtins

str = 9
print(builtins.str(str))
>>> '9'
str(9)
>>>TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

that said, it is not a good practice to overwrite builtins - it can be very confusing for the developer that works with the code after you